# I'm using webview on flutter. Page has favorite link function. How can i call and list favorited links in profile page?

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm using webview on flutter and favorite function at this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example) .
It works fine, but how can i show favorited links on profile page>favorites?

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class NewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewsScreenState createState() => _NewsScreenState();
}

class _NewsScreenState extends State<NewsScreen> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60.0),
        child: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Haberler',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 25.0),
              )
            ],
          ),

          // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
          actions: <Widget>[
            NavigationControls(
              _controller.future,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            print("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)");
          },
          javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
            _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
          },
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            print('allowing navigation to $request');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            print('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            print('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        );
      }),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: favoriteButton(),
    );
  }

  JavascriptChannel _toasterJavascriptChannel(BuildContext context) {
    return JavascriptChannel(
        name: 'Toaster',
        onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(content: Text(message.message)),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget favoriteButton() {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> controller) {
          if (controller.hasData) {
            return FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final String url = (await controller.data!.currentUrl())!;
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                  SnackBar(content: Text('Favorited $url')),
                );
              },
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.favorite,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            );
          }
          return Container();
        });
  }
}

class NavigationControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationControls(this._webViewControllerFuture)
      : assert(_webViewControllerFuture != null);

  final Future<WebViewController> _webViewControllerFuture;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<WebViewController>(
      future: _webViewControllerFuture,
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
        final bool webViewReady =
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
        final WebViewController controller = snapshot.data!;
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                      if (await controller.canGoBack()) {
                        await controller.goBack();
                      } else {
                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(content: Text("Geçmiş Bulunamadı")),
                        );
                        return;
                      }
                    },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              onPressed: !webViewReady
                  ? null
                  : () async {
                      if (await controller.canGoForward()) {
                        await controller.goForward();
                      } else {
                        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          const SnackBar(content: Text("Geçmiş Bulunamadı")),
                        );
                        return;
                      }
                    },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```